# Dramatically increased Read Ops in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am playing with Cassandra on out testing environment. I have 3 nodes of C* (version 3.11) in cluster and 3 column families with replication factor 2 and SizeTieredCompactionStrategy. Each node is deployed to AWS r4.large instance with two EBS gp2 disks - 100GB for commit log and 300GB for data.
2 column families are write-only, our applications write quite a lot to these tables (about 800 - 1000 inserts per second in total) and never read them. Third column family is a counter-table, which is used like 'Increment and Get' pattern: about 200 increments and gets per second. Each counter is updated not that frequently - about 30 times during the whole test.

Everything worked fine for a 5 days, but then read ops/sec on one of nodes stared to grow to >1000 iops, to the disk iops limit:
[image: IOPS graph]

When it reached the limit, response time of selects from counter-table jumped from 2-digit milliseconds to seconds and read io started to grow on the second node.

Here is an output of `nodetool cfstats`:

```
Keyspace : geo
Read Count: 51744711
Read Latency: 12.840126352082631 ms.
Write Count: 201887146
Write Latency: 0.02199966441647553 ms.
Pending Flushes: 0
    Table: gpm
    SSTable count: 5
    Space used (live): 5127907030
    Space used (total): 5127907030
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 102252166
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.41318162863841235
    Number of keys (estimate): 32583794
    Memtable cell count: 51001
    Memtable data size: 3072328
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0
    Memtable switch count: 176
    Local read count: 51530318
    Local read latency: NaN ms
    Local write count: 97595727
    Local write latency: NaN ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bloom filter false positives: 0
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 80436992
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 80436952
    Index summary off heap memory used: 21046326
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 768888
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 87
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 149
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 112
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
    Dropped Mutations: 0
```

I can't find any explanation why is it happening. I performed the same test twice (starting from empty database) and both times it failed identically after 5-6 days from the beginning. 
Here is tracing of typical query which selects counter (the only type of selects performed during test):

```
                                                                                                                                            Execute CQL3 query | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.110000 | 172.31.16.220 |              0 | 172.31.16.220
                                            Parsing select * from geo.gpm where usr = '57469' and lat = 55.617 and lon = 37.509; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.110000 | 172.31.16.220 |            187 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                             Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.110000 | 172.31.16.220 |            411 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                reading data from /172.31.32.220 [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.110000 | 172.31.16.220 |            736 | 172.31.16.220
   Sending READ message to cassandra-test-skywalker.aws.local/172.31.32.220 [MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-test-skywalker.aws.local/172.31.32.220-Small] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.111000 | 172.31.16.220 |           1184 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                          READ message received from /172.31.16.220 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.31.16.220] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.111000 | 172.31.32.220 |             35 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                         Executing single-partition query on gpm [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5675 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                    Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5745 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                       Skipped 0/5 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5812 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                    Key cache hit for sstable 85 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5906 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                   Key cache hit for sstable 170 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5963 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                   Key cache hit for sstable 191 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117000 | 172.31.32.220 |           5996 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                   Key cache hit for sstable 212 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.117001 | 172.31.32.220 |           6028 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                        Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 217 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.118000 | 172.31.32.220 |           6069 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                       Merged data from memtables and 4 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.118000 | 172.31.32.220 |           6151 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                               Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.118000 | 172.31.32.220 |           6203 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                            Enqueuing response to /172.31.16.220 [ReadStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.118001 | 172.31.32.220 |           6228 | 172.31.16.220
                                                              REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /172.31.32.220 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.31.32.220] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.119000 | 172.31.16.220 |           9891 | 172.31.16.220
Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to cassandra-test-kenobi.aws.local/172.31.16.220 [MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-test-kenobi.aws.local/172.31.16.220-Small] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.119000 | 172.31.32.220 |           7466 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                              Processing response from /172.31.32.220 [RequestResponseStage-3] | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.120000 | 172.31.16.220 |          10013 | 172.31.16.220
                                                                                                                                              Request complete | 2017-08-28 16:06:44.124753 | 172.31.16.220 |          14753 | 172.31.16.220
```

Any help will be appreciated. Are there any profiling tools which can help me to realise what is wrong?

Comment: You probably reached a point where the sstables had to be compacted. Your debug log should have compaction data, or you may find an sstable on disk with it's file time roughly lining up with the drop in disk read rate (compaction finishing).